# How to fix Virtual directory error when asp.net .sln file open?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, sln-file

I am trying to open my asp.net project but some warning shows. After this warning I have clicked `yes` and they were responding error.

How can I handle this virtual directory problem ?

This error is shown in the Image below
[image]

Comment: Please check your project properties if it is Set up to run on IIS Express or Local IIS

Comment: This project can't open for setup IIS And more think....